# unable to locate package chattr on wsl ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, internet, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get internet works on WSL Ubuntu and one of the solutions is the following

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameservers 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf=false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

but when I try to install chattr command `sudo apt install chattr` it keeps responding with unable to locate package even though the internet is temporarily working

Also, I tried to use `e2fsprogs` but for some reason even if the command seems to be installed and updated as per shell promote, once I use it the shell responds back with command not found.

Comment: There is a package `e2fsprogs` that provides a `chattr` command. However, in general you shouldn't simply copy and run commands from the web, unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @user535733 because everybody suggests it as part of their solutions

Comment: The `e2fsprogs` package is included with every stock Ubuntu install, even minimal installs. It should not need to be installed separately. Whatever solutions you are looking at seem suspect.

Comment: @user535733 I agree with you, but I'm a newbie with it comes to network configuration so I have no option but to trust people's commands. about e2f it seems to be available yet when I try to use it the shell tells me that the command is not found.

Answer (score 0):

apparently when you add the flag -f to chattr it works
I tried using the command this way
`sudo chattr -f +i /etc/resolv.conf`
and it worked just fine.